# iOS: Production Provisioning Profile has no devices included

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I recently decided to add Push Notifications to my iOS App. I had to create new certificates, then I realised the devices included in the Apple Developer Website weren't up to date. So I had to add my new device with the correct UDID. That's where the issues started. I can't exactly explain all the steps I've taken because I've been constantly deleting and adding new Provisioning Profiles today. Here is the status now:
I have a iOS Team Provisioning Profile, in iOS Development, Managed by xCode, for my app. 
Then, I created my own iOS Production App Store Provisioning Profile, but it always indicates that there are "0 devices" linked to the profile. Impossible to add a device. This obviously creates issues in xCode, because whenever I try to generate new archives, or builds, I'll get issues that my device is not included in the provisioning file.

I've tried deleting them all and recreating them multiple times to no avail. 
Whenever I let xCode try to fix the issue, it ends up with the Provisioning Profile in Build Settings being switched to Automatic, and the Code Signing Identities ALL switch to "iOS Developer". But that obviously fails when I try to build a Release build of my app.

From scratch, what are the steps to generate a valid iOS Distribution Profile for my app, that includes my device, and that I can use for Push Notifications?

**EDIT**: I now understand that I can't add a Device to a Distribution Profile and that this is not necessary. Thanks a lot. Still, I get the following message whenever I try to build on my device:

```
Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “...”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.
```

ANd when I click on fix, it switches back to everything I explained above.

Comment: App Store provisioning profiles don't have devices linked to them because they're for distributing through the app store, not for testing on specific devices.  What happens when you try to archive using the "Generic iOS Device" option, instead of an explicit device plugged into your computer?

Comment: You _**CANNOT**_ add devices to your _**Distribution Profile**_.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I was just deeply confused for a while. I just can't remember what Provisioning Profile I had in my settings before I started messing around with the Push Notification stuff. I do have to generate a new Distribution Profile to be able to include Push Notifications, right?

Comment: https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/

Comment: @bloemy Yes, create a new profile for distribution and make sure its push notification is ON in developer.apple.com, app ids section. Delete all previous distribution profiles from keychain access, so there is no duplicate profile. Now select the new profile from project and target , build settings.

Comment: Cheers. And what about the Code Signing Identity values for Debug and Release?

Comment: For Debug, I would recommend specifying "iOS Developer" as your code signing identity and for Release, use 'iOS Distribution".  Use "Automatic" for both for Provisioning Profile. Then make sure you've deleted all your old certs and provisioning profiles from your Mac.  This should allow you to get new provisioning profiles without having to change your Build Settings.  Have you added Push Notifications to your Prod Distribution Profile?